# scrollTo - jQuery plugin. Scrolls fine, but trying to scroll back up is jaggered and 'stuck'

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors, scrollto

I'm using the scrollTo plugin and executing it in a callback function of an animate method within a 'click' event.

The page scrolls just fine, but then if I use the mousewheel or scrollbar to try and go back up, it won't let me. It's just kind of stuck and fights with me - creating a jumping effect. after a second or so, it resumes to normal behaviour.

I can't show the exact place this is happening (not permitted to) but I have copied my code below:

```
// This function finds the first item that has an opacity set to 1 (full)
function moveIt() {
    var theItem = $('.work').filter( function(j) { return $(this).css('opacity') == 1 } ).eq(0);
    $("html").scrollTo( theItem, 350 );
}

$("#work-menu-client a").click(

    function () {

        var val = $(this).attr("href");
        val = val.substring(1, val.length);

        if( val.length ) { 


            $(".work[data-client*='" + val + "']").animate({
                opacity: 1
                }, 350, function() {    
                    // Complete
            });


            $(".work:not([data-client*='" + val + "'])").animate({
                opacity: 0.05
                }, 350, function() {

                    moveIt();

            });


        }

        return false;

    }, 

    function () {
        return false;   
    }

);
```

Don't worry about what this whole thing does, but there's something not right with placing this code into the callback function. Almost like it keeps looping / repeating the callback so I can't go back up.

(If you want to know, basically, a menu allows me to fade in and out certain items based on their attribute, then I scroll to the first occurance of where the opacity wasn't faded out.)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I located someone with a similar problem but it hasn't been solved and there's little feedback on there: [JQUERY, scrollTo, after scrolling down, the page won't let me scroll up for a second... Y?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941160/jquery-scrollto-after-scrolling-down-the-page-wont-let-me-scroll-up-for-a-sec)

Many thanks,
Michael.

EDIT: In fact, I have just noticed that I can't scroll down either...so essentially, I'm stuck in the position it sent me to.

Comment: UPDATE: I have figured out what caused this. My selector logic was getting more than one element and even though only one was showing due to eq(0), scrollTo was working on multiple elements. Just beware about this if you're having a similar problem. I changed my selector logic and now it works.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue too, but the bug/fix was not about the selector logic.

The problem was that I was binding click handlers onto the anchor that was triggering the scrollTo more than once, without unbinding old ones.  I was implementing ajax loading and re-registering event handlers but not de-registering old ones.  The fix just involved a call to `$(selector).off() before $(selector).on(...)`, which I didn't have to change since it was behavior that I still wanted.